# Building one-to-many pipelines with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to create a small script in python that works with the twitter API to perform several steps using asyncio to increase the speed of the script, but I am having some trouble coming up with a nice and clear solution to the problem. Here's what I want to do:

I have a list of tweet IDs (in the thousands). For each ID, I need to:

1. Check if it still exists
2. If it exists, ask the API to delete it
3. If it was successfully deleted, write the ID to a file.

I have already figured out how to do this one by one, but I want to reduce the number of API calls (since Twitter API is rate limited). I noticed that, for step 1, you can check tweets in chunks of 100, instead of one by one, but then, you can only delete tweets one by one.

So I wrote the following code that uses this fact (just a mockup for now):

```
async def check_and_stage_delete(ids):
    responses = await get_tweets(ids)
    tweets_that_still_exist = check_tweets(responses)
    [asyncio.create_task(delete_and_stage_write(id)) for id in tweets_that_still_exist]

async def delete_and_stage_write(id):
    response = await delete_tweet(id)
    if was_deleted(response):
        asyncio.create_task(write_to_file(id))

async def main():
   tweets = [...] # list of ids
   batches = batched(tweets, 100) # batches of 100 ids using a more-itertools function
   tasks = [asyncio.create_task(check_and_stage_delete(batch)) for batch in batches]

asyncio.run(main)
```

The problem I see with this is that each coroutine is not only responsible for doing its own stuff (checking, deleting or writing tweets), but also needs to schedule the next step in the pipeline. This is not that much of a problem right now, but I will also want to add code to catch exceptions in the future, as well as the ability to cancel all pending tasks, so the code might get more messy.

Moreover, I just feel like there has to be a way to independently write the steps of the pipeline, and assemble it on the outside. So, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `asyncio.create_task(write_to_file(id))` How does the writing work? If this all going to the same file, you'll probably want to use a queue and have a single actor writing into it, otherwise you might get strange behavior in the writing with contention from multiple writers.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using unstructured concurrency (`asyncio.create_task()`). Instead, you can use `asyncio.gather()` or `asyncio.TaskGroup`. These will allow you to wait for all tasks to finish and optionally to cancel the tasks  all at once. The `asyncio.gather()` function also allows you to grab the returned exceptions so that you can inspect and handle them.

Because your program looks like a pipeline, you could also try to use `asyncio.Queue` to organize the flow of data at each stage.